# How to make a reflective object have a solid texture in Blender internal?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

Using Blender internal, how would I go about adding a non-reflective (or less reflective) image texture to a highly reflective object? For example, how to make the black printing on the shiny gold lego C-3PO be non-reflective, like the following photo of the physical object:

[image: Example of a shiny gold lego C-3PO]

(when I apply an image texture to a highly reflective material, the image gets washed-out/diluted by the reflective value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to experiment with the [Influence](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/influence/material.html) settings of your texture. If you set your image to influence "Intensity" in the "Specular" section it will change the brightness of the specular highlight, keeping it from being washed out. **NOTE:** You'll have to turn *off* it's influence of other factors.

If your image is in color, it might not affect the specular intensity the way you want, by default. You may have to create a B&W version of the image that controls where the specular is brightest (white) and where the specular is dimmest (black), and then use the color version to influence the surface color. If you're up for a challenge, you can actually make a B&W version of your color image just using the texture settings in Blender. That way, you don't have two images to update when you make changes.

Depending on how sophisticated you want to get, you can also have another B&W version that's slightly different for controlling the hardness, another for controlling the specular color, and another for mirror.

I hope that helps!